# How to do INSERT OR IGNORE with H2 database?

Tags: java, sql, h2

I'm trying to insert a record into H2 database, if it is *absent*. If it is *present*, I want to ignore the entire operation. Is it possible? I've seen MERGE command, but can't figure out how it can help, since it updates a record in any case.

Comment: It's not possible to do _nothing_ with an H2 MERGE statement. It always updates existing rows.

Comment: @eis as far as I understand, `MERGE` will update the record, if it exists. But I don't need that, as my question explains. I don't need any changes to happen when the record exists. Do I miss something?

Comment: @yegor256 yes, I agree on that. I think I misunderstood the comment by a_horse_with_no_name, which is why I deleted my comment.